# Rewriting a sub-query into a single query so it can be put into a view in SQL

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, sql-view

I have a homework problem where I have this schema:

```
Emp(eid:integer, ename:string, age:integer, salary:real)
Works(eid:integer, did:integer)
Dept(did:integer, managerid:integer)
```

And with this, I am supposed to construct a single view entitled `Manager` giving the `eid`, `ename` of an employee and his/her manager's `eid` and `ename`. Then I am supposed to say if the view is updatable, and why/why not.

So, I successfully created the query to do get this information:

```
SELECT
    Employee.eid,
    Employee.ename,
    Manager.mid,
    Manager.ename
  FROM 
    (
      SELECT Dept.managerid AS mid, ename, did
      FROM Emp
      INNER JOIN Dept
      ON Emp.eid = Dept.managerid
    ) as Manager
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT ename, Emp.eid, did
      FROM Emp
      INNER JOIN Works
      ON Emp.eid = Works.eid
    ) AS Employee
  ON 
    Employee.did = Manager.did
    AND
    Employee.eid != Manager.mid;
```

But when I add `CREATE VIEW Manager AS` to the top of the statement to create a view out of it, I end up getting this error: `View's SELECT contains a sub query in the FROM clause`

For reference, I have uploaded my code to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cff00). The only thing that needs to be done is to add `CREATE VIEW Manager AS` right before the `SELECT` statement at the bottom.

I was wondering if there is a way I could somehow refactor this statement to not use a nested `SELECT` so that I can only use a single view. Unfortunately I am limited to using only one view for my assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subqueries are an unnecessarily complicated way of going about this. Easier just to join `emp` to `works`, `work` to `dept`, and then `dept` back to `emp`.

```
select e.*, e2.*
  from emp e
    inner join works w
      on w.eid = e.eid
    inner join dept d
      on w.did = d.did
    inner join emp e2
      on d.managerid = e2.eid
```

[updated your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cff00/3)

To create a view from this, you would need to alias the resulting columns, since there are duplicates. eg:

```
select e.eid as `employee_id`, e.ename as `employee_name`, e2.eid as `manager_id`, e2.ename as `manager_name`
```

instead of `select e.*, e2.*`

Comment: I'm brand new to SQL so i'm kind of confused on how these joins work? Is it joining emp to works, then emp to dept, then emp to a second emp? Or is it creating some kind of virtual table to store all of the join information as it goes along, and it joins on those?

Comment: Also, adding `CREATE VIEW Manager AS` before this gives me an error stating: `Duplicate column name 'eid' `

Comment: @Alex i've added how to alias the columns.  `joins` are the backbone of a relational database, they are the 'relational' part.  your second description is closer to the fact, it builds up the result set in memory. so after joining emp to works, you have (emp, works), then that joins to dept and you get (emp, works, dept), then that joins to emp (with a different alias and conditions)  [this description looks okay](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)